# Integral $f(x)$ times integral $g(x)/f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I have an equation of the following form:

$$I=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\int_{a}^{b}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

Where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous/differentiable everywhere, but are not specifically defined in this context. I feel like there's something I could do to simplify that right hand side. But I don't have any clear idea on how to do that. Any ideas? Is it even possible/advisable to play with it?

Comment: Have you tried using integration by parts?

Comment: @panini The functions are not specific functions -- they could be anything in the context I'm working with. So I'm not sure how that would apply.

Comment: @Musicrafter12 I very much doubt there being a general answer to this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do anything with it, but we could write it as: $$\int_a^bf(y)dy\int_a^b\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int_a^b\int_a^b\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}g(x)dxdy$$